# android xml file error

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I designed a basic xml layout for a calculator app. It shows fine in the graphical view but the app does'nt start.I commented the entire java part. But the `logcat` shows nearly 20 errors of `java.lang.Please` help.

This is the `xml` file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:weightSum="100" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="25"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <TextView android:layout_weight="100" android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="0"></TextView>            
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_weight="15"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">


    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="7"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="8"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="9"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/mult"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="*"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>

     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="15"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">


    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="4"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="5"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/six"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="6"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/div"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="/"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="15"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">


    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="1"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="2"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="3"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="C"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="15"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">



    <Button android:layout_weight="50" android:id="@+id/zero"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="0"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="+"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="-"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="15"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">


    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/allclear"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="AC"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_weight="50" android:id="@+id/eq"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="="
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_weight="25" android:id="@+id/perc"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="%"
        android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It would be better if you post logcat.

Comment: Plz show your entire xml file including its header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add  **android:layout_width="0dp"**  **OR**   **android:layout_width="size in dp"** to each button.
like this

```
`<Button     
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="25" 
         android:id="@+id/seven"
         android:text="7"
         android:textSize="35dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white">
 </Button>`
```

Comment: In your code ,also you missed android:layout_height="" in some places. please read your code carefully and add android:layout_height=""  XML attributes .

Comment: i changed width to 25 dp for four buttons each.but still cant the app doesnt open

Answer (score 0):

While you are using layout_weight and weightSum, you also need `android:layout_width` in each button. Set the `android:layout_width` to `0dp`.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of your elements miss the [`android:layout_height=""`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_height) element.

You should give the [Layouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) section of the Android developers guide a read.

Comment: layout_height i had set to fill_parent in the first and wrap_content from there on.do i have to change all to layout_height = "" ????

Comment: Yes. I've added a link to my answer that describes a lot of general knowledge on Android Layouts.

Answer (score 0):

for every Layout It must have two Characteristics

```
android:layout_width=""
```

and

```
android:layout_height=""
```

but here you are just adding its single property 
that is 
width and not the height 
add the height and then check

Answer (score 0):

Your Views and ViewGroup  miss the  XML attributes `android:layout_height` or `ndroid:layout_width`

Answer (score 0):

Please use some layout height and width with proper dp or something else for height and width.

ie like

`android:layout_width="50dp"`

`android:layout_height="80dp"`